# If you were to calculate the energy flux across a 1m sphere around a nuclear detonation, at what sort of timescales would you see peak wattage?

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics

If you plotted watts over time with t=0 at the moment the bomb is triggered, what does the graph look like for a nuclear bomb and where do you see peak energy production. I'm not looking for state secrets, I'm just looking for rough orders of magnitude.

Comment: Welcome Adam. A nuclear explosion takes place ["as fast as the shake of a lamb's tail"](https://www.atomicarchive.com/science/fission/time-of-reaction.html), which is reportedly how Los Alamos physicists described the microsecond that it takes all the fission reactions to complete.  After a microsecond, the bomb is a ball of plasma ["several meters in diameter with a temperature of tens of millions of degrees Celsius"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_weapon_design#Fission).